# Magento 2 simple products: How to show lowest price first on category and product page?

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice

we have staggered prices for simple products for different products.

We would like to show the lowest price first on the category page as well as on the product page. That is the lowest price which we have set via "Customer Group Price" in the respective product.

For example customer group "General" 1 product = 20 € per product, 3 products = 15 € per product.

For B2B customers after login even more customer price groups. For example:

[image]

Does anyone have a hint, how to achieve this?

Best regards